# What is the linux-oem-20.04-edge package?

Tags: drivers, wireless, package-management, 20.04, bluetooth

What is linux-oem-20.04-edge?

Someone said that with this package I can use my wifi driver, and I'd like to know what is it before installing it

> The driver is included in linux-firmware 1.187.7+ And works fine with
> Ubuntu 20.04 + linux-oem-20.04-edge + Developper updates (proposed)
> I'm using my XPS 9310 with wifi and bluetooth without problems since
> one month.

I think  `linux-firmware 1.187.7+` is the collection of all firmwares for hardwares that support ubuntu, it contains the wifi firmware.

What are developer updates and what he mant by (proposed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `linux-image-oem-20.04-edge` package contains the latest kernel v. 5.10, [as you can see here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/linux-image-oem-20.04-edge). And there's a good chance it has support for newer WiFi hardware.